# Reactstrap modals

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I want to take advantage of `reactstarp modal`. I also use it in the project `eslintrc`. I am showing such a mistake 
`Line 17:  Unused state field: 'modal'  react/no-unused-state
  Line 26:  Unused state field: 'modal'  react/no-unused-state`

this is my code

```
class AccountModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false,
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    const { state } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      modal: !state.modal,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { state } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>Delete account</Button>
        <Modal isOpen={state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Deleting your account will remove all of
            your information from our database.
            This cannot be undone.
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Delete Account</Button>
            {' '}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I do not know why the state is unused. I have copied the above code from the reactstarp documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the state correctly. Try;

```
toggle() {
    const { modal } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      modal: !modal,
    }); 
}
```

You should be able to access the modal property like in the render method as well.

**Explanation**

```
const { state } = this.state;
```

this means that you are looking for an attribute with the name "state" inside "this.state",

```
this.state = {
   modal: false,
};
```

whereas there is only one attribute named "modal" inside "this.state".

Comment: thanks. or maybe you send some article about what has been done before, because it works but I do not understand it :<

Comment: I have added a little explanation.

Comment: Also look at *destructuring* in JS